# Expo bare workflow monorepo

Tags: react-native, expo, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, expo-yarn-workspaces

I have successfully setup managed workflow as a monorepo, but since I needed to add Bluetooth to my project, I had to eject into bare workflow and has been trying to connect back to monorepo with no success. Would really appreciate any kind of guidance.

Comment: have you solve this?